# FuzzyFinder in vim - prevent duplicate filenames in Windows

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I'm using the FuzzyFinder plugin for vim (specifically with gvim on Windows). It works great, except for one problem: it has many duplicate filenames.

As far as I can tell, this happens because it's case sensitive to filenames, whereas Windows is not. So when I open a file from someplace that lists the directory as "C:\", and another place that lists it as "c:\", I get two different filenames.

Does anyone know of a way that I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not ask this on SO: first search fuzzyfinder documenation, second [create a new issue](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/issues/new) and let the author fix if nothing from the documentation worked. Have you tried `g:fuf_ignoreCase` option?

Comment: Thanks, I looked through all the fuzzyfinder docs and couldn't find anything. I've created a new issue on bitbucket, I'll update here if this is really a bug or if I'm just being stupid.